# Google play apk crashes after downloading

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

After publishing and downloading it from google play, my game crashes only on the first startup. Does anyone know about this?
i am using google play services and google admob of the latest of versions.
My unity version : 2018.3.6f1

Help me here, I am stuck![image]

Comment: Does this happen only on your device or did you try installing it on different devices as well?

Comment: tried it on different devices, same result.

Answer (score 0):

On research, found out that it could be an Admod problem and so remove the following code from your Admob Plugin Manifest.

```
<receiver 
  android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver" 
  android:exported="true"> 
  <intent-filter> 
  <action 
  android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

If the problem still persists, delete the current Admob plugin folder and install the latest version from [GoogleMobileAds.unitypackage](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v3.0.4)